# convert a dynamic circle layout to oval or ellipse in android

Tags: java, android, geometry, ellipse

I  have a image group with three images perpendicularly, those group forms a circle, i have created it as circle view couldn't adjust its width to make it oval, since i have three stacked images one above one i couldn't adjust all those images  the code as below's

```
 static int Standard_height = 160;
 static int Cam_Size = 50;
 static int Segment_Size = 55;
 static int TextSize = 10;

 private void SetLayoutDesign() {
        Layout_Frame.removeAllViews();
        Segments = sharedpreferences.getInt(Vars.Selected_Segment_Count, 4);
        int imageGap = Segment_Size + 5;
        int size = Segment_Size + ((16 - (Segments + 1)));
        int imageSize = Cam_Size - Segments;

        for (int i = 0; i < Segments; i++) {
            // Create some quick TextViews that can be placed.

            String StateName = Vars.Segment_State + "_" + i;
            int state = sharedpreferences.getInt(StateName, 0);
            String TypeName = Vars.Segment_Type + "_" + i;
            int type = sharedpreferences.getInt(TypeName, 0);
            Segment_Button[i] = new ImageButton(act);
            Segment_Name[i] = new TextView(act);
            if (type == 0) {
                Segment_Name[i].setText((i + 1) + "");
                if (state == 1) {
                    Segment_Button[i].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sort_none);
                } else {
                    Segment_Button[i].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sort_off);
                }
            } else if (type == 1) {
                Segment_Name[i].setText((i + 1) + "\nMS");
                if (state == 1) {
                    Segment_Button[i].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sort_ms);
                } else {
                    Segment_Button[i].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sort_off);
                }
            } else if (type == 2) {
                Segment_Name[i].setText((i + 1) + "\nFR");
                if (state == 1) {
                    Segment_Button[i].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sort_fr);
                } else {
                    Segment_Button[i].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sort_off);
                }
            } else if (type == 3) {
                Segment_Name[i].setText((i + 1) + "\nSR");
                if (state == 1) {
                    Segment_Button[i].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sort_sr);
                } else {
                    Segment_Button[i].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sort_off);
                }
            }
            Segment_Name[i].setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            Segment_Name[i].setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            Segment_Name[i].setTextSize(TextSize);
            Segment_Name[i].setId(Segment_Text_Ids[i]);
            Segment_Name[i].setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
            Segment_Button[i].setId(Segment_Ids[i]);
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams lp1 = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(imageSize, imageSize);
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams lp = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(size, size);
            lp.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
            lp1.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;

            Segment_Button[i].setLayoutParams(lp);
            Segment_Button[i].setOnClickListener(this);
            Segment_Button[i].setOnLongClickListener(this);
            Segment_Name[i].setLayoutParams(lp);

            float angleDeg = i * 360.0f / Segments - 90.0f;
            float angleRad = (float) (angleDeg * Math.PI / 180.0f);

            Segment_Button[i].setTranslationX(Standard_height * (float) Math.cos(angleRad));
            Segment_Button[i].setTranslationY(Standard_height * (float) Math.sin(angleRad));
            Layout_Frame.addView(Segment_Button[i]);

            Segment_Name[i].setTranslationX(Standard_height * (float) Math.cos(angleRad));
            Segment_Name[i].setTranslationY(Standard_height * (float) Math.sin(angleRad));
            if (Segments % 2 == 0 && Segments != 0) {
                Segment_Name[i].setRotation((180 / Segments));
            } else {
                Segment_Name[i].setRotation(0);
            }
            Layout_Frame.addView(Segment_Name[i]);

            FCam_Button[i] = new ImageButton(act);
            FCam_Button[i].setId(FCam_Ids[i]);
            String FCamName = Vars.FCam_State + "_" + i;
            int FCamState = sharedpreferences.getInt(FCamName, 0);
            if (FCamState == 0) {
                FCam_Button[i].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.f_camera_off_image);
            } else {
                FCam_Button[i].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.f_camera_on_image);
            }

            FCam_Button[i].setLayoutParams(lp1);
            FCam_Button[i].setOnClickListener(this);
            FCam_Button[i].setTranslationX((Standard_height + imageGap) * (float) Math.cos(angleRad));
            FCam_Button[i].setTranslationY((Standard_height + imageGap) * (float) Math.sin(angleRad));
            FCam_Button[i].setRotation(angleDeg + 90.0f);
            Layout_Frame.addView(FCam_Button[i]);

            RCam_Button[i] = new ImageButton(act);
            RCam_Button[i].setId(RCam_Ids[i]);
            String RCamName = Vars.RCam_State + "_" + i;
            int RCamState = sharedpreferences.getInt(RCamName, 0);
            if (RCamState == 0) {
                RCam_Button[i].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.r_camera_off_image);
            } else {
                RCam_Button[i].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.r_camera_on_image);
            }
            RCam_Button[i].setLayoutParams(lp1);
            RCam_Button[i].setOnClickListener(this);

            RCam_Button[i].setTranslationX((Standard_height - imageGap) * (float) Math.cos(angleRad));
            RCam_Button[i].setTranslationY((Standard_height - imageGap) * (float) Math.sin(angleRad));
            RCam_Button[i].setRotation(angleDeg + 90.0f);
            Layout_Frame.addView(RCam_Button[i]);


        }

        if (Segments % 2 == 0 && Segments != 0) {
            Layout_Frame.setRotation(-(180 / Segments));
        } else {
            Layout_Frame.setRotation(0);
        }

        SetUserLevelControls();
    }
```

> This is the current layout

[image: current layout]

> This is the desired layout

[image: desired view]